# Android Emulator is too big, `scale` argument depricated

Tags: android-emulator

I'm playing with *Visual Studio 2019* and *Xamarin*.

`Android Emulator` looks very big. I can manually scale it to desired size with help of mouse, but each new development session it returns to default huge size. I'm aware of `-scale 0.x` argument, but nowadays it deprecated (why?) and IDE says, it will be skipped.

Do I have any other option to scale down size of Android Emulator?
I prefer not to change screen size of emulated device and its pixel density.